# Referencing current SKScene from a SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In Apple's sample adventure game, they add sprites to the scene like so:

Scene file has this function:

```
- (void)addNode:(SKNode *)node atWorldLayer:(APAWorldLayer)layer {
    SKNode *layerNode = self.layers[layer];
   [layerNode addChild:node];
}
```

Class extending SKSpriteNode implements:

```
APAMultiplayerLayeredCharacterScene *scene = (id)[self scene];
[scene addNode:emitter atWorldLayer:APAWorldLayerAboveCharacter];
```

This feels a bit dirty to me as it is basically a global function call from inside the class back out to the current scene. Is this acceptable practice, and are there any alternative approaches? Ideas that come to mind are:

1) Pass the scene reference into the class and store it is a local member variable

2) Notification/event listener setup

As I'm new to Objective-C, I would love to hear if I'm missing or overlooking an ideal solution or approach to this type of code flow. Thanks!

Comment: 1) how is that superior to simply accessing the scene property of your node, as shown in your code snippet.  Is it simply to avoid the casting?

Comment: I guess I'm just looking for something more explicit. In this case, SKSpriteNode conveniently knows it's own scene using `[self scene]`. Perhaps a better question/example would be if one SKSpriteNode is attacking another. In that situation, would you store a reference like `Character* target` and then later call a method directly on that variable like `[target doDamage]`

Comment: In that scenario I imagine doDamage might be called after a physics contact occurred meaning no reference need be stored.
However if you wanted your enemy to move towards a Character then you might want to assign that character to a target property on your node so you could access it again later.
As with a lot of things it is probably subjective.

Comment: I could be miss-understanding the question but there is a property on SKSpriteNode that contains a pointer to the scene the sprite belongs to. If your looking to compare one sprite with another then you can use childNodeWithName to search for the other node. If your going to be referring to the same object a lot (like enemies looking for the player) you need to keep a copy of the search result so that your just doing a lookup and not a search thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding other nodes the scene from any given node, you will need a reference to the parent object you wish to add the node to.

This could be

- the scene
- the parent of the current node
- the node itself
- some child of any these nodes

These are all accessible via node properties.

A clean way of finding children is with [childNodeWithName:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName%3a)

`[[self.scene childNodeWithName:@"childLayerNodeIWantToAddStuffTo"] addChild:node];`

Comment: Gotcha. Accepting this and the comments above as the accepted answer. Basically, the discussion shows me that all approaches are acceptable and that none of them are bad practice. Calling a parent scene method, searching the tree for a node, storing a reference that is used directly and using global events like physics or touch are all valid ways for one class to call a method on another class.